# What is 棒打鸡丝拌拉皮?

Tags: translation

I was in China for a week about a month ago. My brother photographed the menu pics of two dishes, namely `梨汤顿燕窝` and `棒打鸡丝拌拉皮`. The first one I figured out to be `Lítāng dùn yànwō`, or `swallow nests stewed in pear soup`. The second one transliterates to `bàng dǎ jī sī bàn lāpí`, but I cannot make sense of it. Word by word it should be "stick hit chicken thread mix facelifts". So what does that mean? What is this dish?

I tried googling and saw [this](http://www.xinshipu.com/zuofa/83022), which says `鸡丝拉皮`, `jīsī lāpí`. I read through it and I understand how it is prepared and what it is, except for one thing: what is `干粉皮`, `gān fěn pí`? And is this the same as `棒打鸡丝拌拉皮` or is there a difference in preparation, or perhaps it's something entirely different?

PS Any suggestions for tags are welcome :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of 棒打(stick hit)  as "**stick tenderized**" (tenderize the chicken meat by **hitting** it repeatedly with a **stick**)

鸡丝 is **shredded chicken**

拌 is  "**mix** / **stir**"

拉皮 is a **wide noodle** made of 木薯粉 (**cassava** powder)

棒打鸡丝拌拉皮 = stick tendered, shredded chicken, stir mixed with wide cassava noodle

**picture of 拉皮**:
[image: 拉皮]

*p.s: It should be 炖(stew)/dùn/, not 顿(pause)/dùn/ in 梨汤炖燕窝. They used the wrong character*

Comment: So far as I know, 拉皮 is a kind of food, as explained in the answer, popular in the northeast area. It can also mean facelift, a cosmetic surgery. The latter meaning is more familiar to Chinese, especially Chinese from south China.

Comment: @TangHo maybe I just didn't check that dùn character :). I typed "litangdunyanwo" and that's what my keyboard gave, maybe I noticed litang was wrong, but the "dun"s are similar so I didn't notice :).